# вопрос про flex (Css)

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, есть блок с width 100% (адаптивная верстка), так вот в нём есть 4 блока, как можно сделать чтобы 3й и 4й были на всю длину и переносились на новую строку (грубо говоря), не сжимаясь с другими? То есть как обычный div со 100% width? пробовал поиграть с flex-basis, flex-grow но что-то ничего не получилось

```
<div class="parent" style="width: 100%; display: flex;">
<div>этот и <div>
<div>этот блок, вместе</div>
<div>а вот этот<div>
<div>и этот, с переносом</div>
```

Картинка:

https://pp.userapi.com/c837422/v837422896/5c405/ksoi9SJcK5M.jpg

Comment: Давайте код того что вы сделали

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan там к сожалению ничего нет, родительский блок с display flex, и внутри него 4 блока.

Comment: Давайте то что есть. Во всех вопросах что здесь зададите.

Comment: flex-wrap?. . .

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan done

Comment: Измените структуру, 1,2-й <div> оберните в один, и тогда можете использовать flex-direction: column;

Comment: @МузыкаСергей я тоже думал про это, но хотелось бы на чистом css чтобы не добавлять дополнительный блок html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для родителя: `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;`. 
Для 1-го `flex: 0 1 25%;`.
Для 2-го `flex: 1 1 auto;`.
Для 3 и 4 блока `flex: 0 1 100%;`.

https://jsfiddle.net/ky3zxds8/1/

Comment: Спасибо, работает как надо.